# send 500 on unhandledRejection

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How do i send 500 error on unhandledRejection

```
process.on("unhandledRejection", function(promise, reason){
   // deal with the rejection here.
   console.log('global error handler');
   console.log(reason);
});


// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.json({"error": err.message});
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.json({"error": err.message});
});
```

Comment: Your error handler is right with http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html
You can send an exanple with code how throw error?

Comment: i wish to know how to send 500 error to client on unhandledRejection